# Сортировка списка строк с числами по значению: '2' < '10'

Tags: python, сортировка

Есть список вида:

```
['KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_2.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_3.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_4.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_1.mx']
```

Необходимо получить отсортированный список вида:

```
['KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_1.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_2.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_3.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_4.mx']
```

Простая сортировка `lst=sorted(lst)` не подходит, если длина списка более 10 элементов.

Comment: related: [Python analog of natsort function (sort a list using a "natural order" algorithm)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2545532/4279)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Простая сортировка lst=sorted(lst) не подходит когда длина списка более 10 элементов.

Дело не в количестве элементов, а в том, что Вам нужно сортировать строко-цифровой кусок. Если заменить 1, 2, 3… на 01, 02, 03…99, можно убедится что сортировка работает ожидаемо.
Тут должна помочь [natsort](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/natsort):

```
from natsort import natsorted
natsorted(lst)
```

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку на natsort! Не знал о его существовании

Answer (score 5):

Строки в списке имеют одинаковый формат, поэтому можно вытащить номер и сортировать по нему.

Вытащить можно, например, через обработку строки или регулярку:

```
import random
import re

# Генерация списка
items = ['KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_%s.mx' % i for i in range(20)]

# Перемешивание элементов списка
random.shuffle(items)

print(items)

# Обычная сортировка не работает
print(sorted(items))
print()


def get_number_1(x):
    return int(x.split('.')[-2].split('_')[-1])


def get_number_2(x):
    match = re.search('KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_(\d+).mx', x)
    return int(match.group(1))


print(sorted(items, key=get_number_1))
print(sorted(items, key=get_number_2))
```

Консоль:

```
['KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_0.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_5.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_17.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_9.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_19.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_15.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_10.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_13.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_18.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_16.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_6.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_14.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_8.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_1.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_7.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_4.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_11.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_12.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_3.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_2.mx']
['KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_0.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_1.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_10.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_11.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_12.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_13.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_14.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_15.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_16.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_17.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_18.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_19.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_2.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_3.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_4.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_5.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_6.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_7.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_8.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_9.mx']

['KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_0.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_1.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_2.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_3.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_4.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_5.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_6.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_7.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_8.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_9.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_10.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_11.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_12.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_13.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_14.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_15.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_16.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_17.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_18.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_19.mx']
['KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_0.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_1.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_2.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_3.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_4.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_5.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_6.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_7.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_8.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_9.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_10.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_11.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_12.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_13.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_14.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_15.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_16.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_17.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_18.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_19.mx']
```

Comment: А если попадётся другой формат строк? ;)

Comment: @MaxU, вот когда попадется, тогда и беспокоиться :) А так, можно было, сделать обработку строки, разбивая ее на кортеж/список, отделяя строки с буквами от строк с числами и сортировать это безобразие :)

Answer (score 0):

Ну, просто нужно привести к int вытаскивая предположительное число.

```
l = ['KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_2.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_3.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_1.mx']
sym = 'E_'
l.sort(key=lambda key: int(key[key.find(sym)+len(sym):-3]))
```

Answer (score -1):

Все отсортировал простой сортировкой:

```
    alist=['KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_2.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_3.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_4.mx', 'KMS1.kmch.pos.out_dE_1.mx']
alist.sort()
print(alist)
```